# Get variables from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-activity

I work simple android app for sending sms. I have 2 activities. One is main for sending 2 different messages with 2 different content but messages send to same number. On secund activity i have 3 fields: one is for input number to send messages, and other two are for message content. When I click save button app save user input and go back to main activity. And here start my problem. How can i send users input for number to send messages and messages content to main activity to send sms with saved user input? I am totally beginner with android developing so please help! Here is my MainActivity.java:

> > package com.example.davor.light;
>
> import android.content.Intent; import
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity; import android.os.Bundle;
>   import android.telephony.SmsManager; import
>   android.telephony.SmsMessage; import android.view.Menu; import
>   android.view.MenuItem; import android.view.View; import
>   android.widget.Button; import android.widget.ImageView; import
>   android.widget.TextView; import android.widget.Toast;
>
> public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>
>     // GUMBI INFORMACIJE
>     Button ukljuci = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ukljuci);
>     Button iskljuci = (Button) findViewById(R.id.iskljuci);
>     Button postavke = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postavke);
>     final ImageView slika = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.slika);
>
>     // INFORMACIJA O PORUCI
>     final String broj = "097";
>     final String ukljuciPoruka = "Uključi";
>     final String iskljuciPoruka = "Isključi";
>
>
>
>     // KLIK NA GUMB ISKLJUČI
>     iskljuci.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             try {
>                 SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
>                 smsManager.sendTextMessage(broj, null, iskljuciPoruka, null, null);
>                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Isključeno! poslano na broj " + broj, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>                 slika.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
>             } catch (Exception e) {
>                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nemoguće isključiti!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>             }
>         }
>     });
>
>     postavke.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             Intent PostavkeActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
>                     Postavke.class);
>             startActivity(PostavkeActivity);
>         }
>     });
> }
>
> @Override
> public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
>     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
>     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
>     return true;
> }
>
> @Override
> public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
>     // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
>     // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
>     // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
>     int id = item.getItemId();
>
>     //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
>     if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
>         return true;
>     }
>
>     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
> } }
> ```

And here is code for my second activity from witch I want to pull users input to MainActivity:

> package com.example.davor.light;
>
> import android.app.Activity; import android.content.Intent; import
>   android.content.SharedPreferences; import
>   android.preference.PreferenceManager; import
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity; import android.os.Bundle;
>   import android.view.Menu; import android.view.MenuItem; import
>   android.view.View; import android.widget.Button; import
>   android.widget.EditText; import android.widget.TextView; import
>   android.widget.Toast;
>
> public class Postavke extends Activity {
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_postavke);
>     gumbZaPovratak();
>
>     SharedPreferences loadSettings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
>     String ucitajBroj = loadSettings.getString("spremiBroj", "");
>     String ucitajUkljuci = loadSettings.getString("spremiUkljuci", "");
>     String ucitajIskljuci = loadSettings.getString("spremiIskljuci", "");
>
>
>     final EditText postavkeBroj = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.postavkeBroj);
>     postavkeBroj.setText(ucitajBroj);
>     final EditText postavkeUkljuci = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.postavkeUkljuci);
>     postavkeUkljuci.setText(ucitajUkljuci);
>     final EditText  postavkeIskljuci = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.postavkeIskljuci);
>     postavkeIskljuci.setText(ucitajIskljuci);
>
>     Button spremi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postavkeSpremi);
>     spremi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v){
>             spremiPostavke("spremiBroj", postavkeBroj.getText().toString());
>             spremiPostavke("spremiUkljuci", postavkeUkljuci.getText().toString());
>             spremiPostavke("spremiIskljuci", postavkeIskljuci.getText().toString());
>             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Spremljeno", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>             finish();
>         }
>     });
>
> }
>
> private void postavkeBroj() {
>     EditText postavkeBroj = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.postavkeBroj);
> }
>
> private void spremiPostavke (String ključ, String vrijednost) {
>     SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
>     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
>     editor.putString(ključ, vrijednost);
>     editor.commit();
> }
>
> private void gumbZaPovratak(){
>     Button nazad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nazad);
>     nazad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             finish();
>         }
>     });
> }
>
>
> @Override
> public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
>     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
>     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_postavke, menu);
>     return true;
> }
>
> @Override
> public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
>     // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
>     // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
>     // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
>     int id = item.getItemId();
>
>     //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
>     if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
>         return true;
>     }
>
>     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
> } }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `startActivityForResult()`

You can refer this link:
http://hmkcode.com/android-startactivityforresult/

Answer (score 0):

In Activity1

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,Activity2.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("var", variable_to_pass);
    startActivity(myIntent);
```

In Activity2

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        intentExtra = extras.getString("var"); // retrieving variable
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add data to an intent like this :

`String messageContent = (EditText) findViewById(yourMessageContentId).getText().toString();
   String messageNumber = (EditText) findViewById(yourMessageNumberId).getText().toString();
   intent.putExtra("com.example.davor.light.MESSAGE_CONTENT", messageContent);
   intent.putExtra("com.example.davor.light.MESSAGE_NUMBER", messageNumber);`

And then get it on the MainActivity :

`Intent intent = getIntent();
String messageNumber = intent.getStringExtra("com.example.davor.light.MESSAGE_NUMBER");
String messageContent = intent.getStringExtra("com.example.davor.light.MESSAGE_CONTENT");`

Answer (score 0):

you can  send information from one activity  to other activity  like bellow

```
    Intent postavkeActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
            Postavke.class);

  Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
  bundle.putString(|"messageKey1", "message content1");
  bundle.putString(|"messageKey2", "message content2");
   postavkeActivity.putExtras(bundle);

    startActivity(PostavkeActivity);
```

in main activity get bundle data like bellow

Bundle b=getIntent.getExtras();

String smsContent=b.getString("messageKey1");